# How to prove that this is an analytic continuation

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, analytic-continuation

I am self studying number theory from Tom Apostol's book and I have a question in proof of theorem 12.9 on page 262.

[image]

If $\psi$ is not principal then $ L(s, \chi) $ will be analytic for all s as product p|k is finite and L(s, $\psi$) will be analytic for all s as $\psi$ is not principal character.

But I have no reason to believe that $\psi$ is not principal. Can you tell if there is some reasoning which I am missing or if my way of proving is wrong, kindly tell the right way.

Thanks!!

Comment: @JeanMarie I am sorry, it's a typo not SMS writing. I beg for apologies.

Comment: On a connected open set, when an analytic (or meromorphic) continuation exists, it is unique. For $\chi$ principal, replacing $L(s,\chi)$ by $(s-1)L(s,\chi)$ then your meromorphic continuation problem becomes an analytic continuation.